# Versioning RESTful services?

Tags: rest, versioning

I have a RESTful web service deployed at http://example.com/v1/SomeResource. One day, a new protocol version (**that is not backwards compatible**) is deployed to http://example.com/v2/SomeResource. From the client of view, this upgrade could occur at any time between two HTTP requests.

How does the server indicate to the client that it no longer supports v1 calls and the client is expected to upgrade to v2? Is there an appropriate response code I can use?

I would want to provide the client with the following information:

1. An incompatible upgrade has taken place. There is no way for the client to use the new service because the protocol could be totally different.
2. The URL of the new client software.
3. A message explaining to the users that they must upgrade.

Comment: For what it's worth, I find Darrel's post (in a separate question) to be enlightening: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972226/how-to-version-rest-uris/975394#975394

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best practices for API versioning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389169/best-practices-for-api-versioning)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Best practice:**

It's probably better to keep the versioning out of the URL and to make the new resources backwards compatible with the old.

**Backwards compatible:**

If you must keep the v1 in the URL, and are making v2 URLs, then you have to decide whether you want to support both formats, or make the old v1 obsolete.  If you decide on making the old v1 obsolete then I would recommend to return 303 or 401 for anyone requesting a v1 URL.

**Making old URLs obsolete:**

I would recommend using 303 See Other.  Or if there is no associated redirect, then use 410 Gone.

[Source](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

> 303 See Other
>
> The response to the request can be
>   found under a different URI and SHOULD
>   be retrieved using a GET method on
>   that resource. This method exists
>   primarily to allow the output of a
>   POST-activated script to redirect the
>   user agent to a selected resource. The
>   new URI is not a substitute reference
>   for the originally requested resource.
>   The 303 response MUST NOT be cached,
>   but the response to the second
>   (redirected) request might be
>   cacheable.
>
> The different URI SHOULD be given by
>   the Location field in the response.
>   Unless the request method was HEAD,
>   the entity of the response SHOULD
>   contain a short hypertext note with a
>   hyperlink to the new URI(s).
>
> Note: Many pre-HTTP/1.1 user agents do not understand the 303
>     status. When interoperability with such clients is a concern, the
>     302 status code may be used instead, since most user agents react
>     to a 302 response as described here for 303.

**Document everything:**

The main thing to be concerned about is whatever you chose to return, just document it in your documentation.  You can decide how you want your service to work, others that want to consume it will follow the documentation.

Answer (score 10):

I recommend the following article by Peter Williams

- [Versioning REST Web Services](http://barelyenough.org/blog/2008/05/versioning-rest-web-services/)

Comment: Also see his full article series: http://barelyenough.org/blog/tag/rest-versioning/

Answer (score 4):

I think you shouldn't do this in the first place, but probably it's too late.

> URIs should also be static so that
>   when the resource changes or the
>   implementation of the service changes,
>   the link stays the same. This allows
>   bookmarking. It's also important that
>   the relationship between resources
>   that's encoded in the URIs remains
>   independent of the way the
>   relationships are represented where
>   they are stored.

From the article [RESTful Web services: The basics](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restful/index.html?ca=drs-).

Comment: Yes, in an ideal world you'd be right, but I'm talking about what to do when you have to break backwards compatibility. If I can maintain backwards compatibility then I'd try to keep the same URIs as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend instead the use of the 301 (301 Moved Permanently). Read [why](http://www.bombaycrow.com/blog/index.php/2008/03/e-directing-web-content-for-seo-301-moved-permanently/).

Hope it helps,
Bruno Figueiredo

Comment: I'm not sure that SEO is relevant for RESTful services (consumed by machines, not people).