# Ensuring APIs are separate

Tags: ruby-on-rails

TL;DR: Crafting an API. Need different fields for different versions. Teach me, wise ones.

I'm currently trying to figure out the best way to craft a versioned API. That is to say, I wish to have a URL of `/api/v1/projects.json` that would show a list of projects with a bunch of fields and `api/v2/projects.json` to show a list of projects with separate fields.

I've been thinking about this problem for about 15 minutes which probably means it's all wrong. At the moment I've got this in my `app/models/project.rb` file:

```
def self.api_fields
  { 
    :v1 => ["name"],
    :v2 => ["name", "tickets_count"]
  }
end
```

Then I can use this in my API controllers (`api/v1/projects_controller.rb`) like this:

```
def index
  respond_with(Project.all(:select => Project.api_fields[:v1]))
end
```

This is great and works as I'd like it to, but there's probably a better way about it. That's your task! Share with me your mountains of API-crafting wisdom.

Bonus points if you come up with a solution that will also allow me to use methods for instances of a model's object, such as a `tickets_count` method on a `Project` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm agree with `polarblau` that you should have multiple controllers for different version of the API. So, I aim for the bonus point of this question.

I think to archive the ability to call `#tickets_count`, you have to override `#as_json` and `#to_xml` methods of the model. I think you'll have to do it like this:

**api/v1/projects_controller.rb**

```
def index
  respond_with Project.all, :api_version => :v1
end
```

**project.rb**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  API_FIELDS = {
    :v1 => { :only => [:name] },
    :v2 => { :only => [:name], :methods => [:tickets_count] }
  }

  def as_json(options = {})
    options.merge! API_FIELDS[options[:api_version]]
    super
  end

  def to_xml(options = {}, &block)
    options.merge! API_FIELDS[options[:api_version]]
    super
  end
end
```

However, if you don't mind the mess in the controller, I think specifying `:only` and `:methods` in `respond_with` call in the controller might be a good idea too, as you don't have to override those `#as_json` and `#to_xml` methods.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a comment:

Have you had a look a these yet?

http://devoh.com/posts/2010/04/simple-api-versioning-in-rails

[Best practices for API versioning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389169/best-practices-for-api-versioning)

devoh.com suggest to split the versions already at a routing level, which seems like a good idea:

```
map.namespace(:v1) do |v1|
  v1.resources :categories
  v1.resources :products
end

map.namespace(:v2) do |v2|
  v2.resources :categories, :has_many => :products
end
```

Then you could use different controllers to return the different fields.

Comment: This is what I'm already doing, using different controllers to return the different fields. That part I've definitely nailed I think. The question is more along the lines of "is this the right way to do it?"

Comment: Feels like a good way to me, but that's why I've started the answer with "Just a comment:" — I'm not confident enough in my wisdom ;) .

Comment: You should also have a directory structure for your API controllers like `app/controllers/api/v2/categories_controller.rb`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, as you know, that whatever you expose allows the end-client to create a direct dependency. Having said that, if you directly expose your models to the world, e.g. http://domain.com/products.json, whenever you change your Products model you have a limited number of options:

1. The end-client must live with it and behave much like a "schemaless database". You say that it's going to change, and voila it's done (reads clients will have to deal with it)!
2. You add a more enterprise-like versioning to your API. That's meas that at a more advanced level what you expose to the end-client are not your models. Instead you expose public objects, which in turn can be versioned. This is called a Data Transfer Object (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)

If we wished to pursue the 2nd approach we could do the following:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class PublicProject
  def to_json(version = API_VERSION)
    self.send("load_#{version}_project").to_json
  end

  private
    def load_v1_project
      project = load_v2_project
      # logic that transforms a current project in a project that v1 users can understand
    end

    def load_v2_project
      Project.find...
    end
end
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Mount a Sinatra app in routes at /api/v1 to handle your API calls. Makes it easier to add a new API and still be backwards compatible until you deprecate it.

Comment: It's for Rails 3 in Action. I don't want to use Sinatra for this because of that reason. I think Rails should be capable of doing this just fine too.