# Confusion about PayPal API Version #'s?

Tags: paypal

I'm completely confused about the version numbers.  I found the documentation that shows up to API version 82.0 and the changes that were made in that version here:

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_PreviousAPIVersionsNVP

However, when I use the integration wizard here (for C#/ASP.NET):

https://www.paypal-labs.com/integrationwizard/ecpaypal/main.php

... it generations a paypal functions for version "2.3"... no where near version "82.0".

What is the difference? Aside from the version numbers, they appear to be using the same API.  If there is a difference, where can i find documentation on the API that is version 2.3?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The integration wizard is just outdated and stems from a time before they started using 'large version numbers' such as 65, 68, 81, 82, 83, etc.
106.0 is the current latest version.
You can find the latest version of the API's available by loading the WSDL at https://www.paypalobjects.com/wsdl/PayPalSvc.wsdl and looking at the ns:version. This is the latest available API version.

New changes may be introduced with new API versions, but core functionality would remain the same.
For example, parallel payments is only available with API version 65.1 (before that PAYMENTREQUEST didn't exist).

Read also [Best practices for API versioning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389169/best-practices-for-api-versioning)

Comment: thanks for the answer. Considering that integration wizard is outdated, I still used it (with version 76.0) and the paypalfunctions.cs file that is generated seems to still fit/work well. Would you happen to know if it's safe for me to keep using that... or is it wwaaay outdated.

Comment: It works, but it lacks new functionality such as parallel payments, support for digital goods, 'line items' (item details), etcetera. But if you don't need all that, no need to change. Plus you can always add it yourself manually later on.

Answer (score 0):

Now, Paypal API version is "114.0"