# WCF WebAPI client does not know about server types

Tags: wcf, wcf-web-api

I am following along in the .6 release of the WCF Web API chm file.  I have built my service and everything works fine when I access it via IE.  But when I create my console app, I don't understand how the client can know about the "contact" type.  Sure I can add a reference, but how would some other client out there in the world know about the types?

```
List<Contact> contacts = resp.Content.ReadAs<List<Contact>>();
```

How would a client know about changes to the Contact class?Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every property on your client type that matches a property (Name/Type) in the response type is mapped by ReadAs<T>.

If you have a string property "Name" on your response type and your client type, its value is being parsed.

You don't need a reference.

Update: If you don't want to work with a contacts type on the client side you could try something like this:

```
var json = JsonValue.Parse(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
```

If your contact type on the server side had a property "Name" you should be able to do the following:

```
var name = json["Name"];
```

(Assuming your response was a single contact - in case of List<Contact> "json" would be of type JsonArray - you should get a clue... [here](http://blog.alexonasp.net/post/2011/11/15/Using-JsonValue-and-JsonArray-in-WCF-Web-API.aspx) is a sample showing usage of JsonValue and JsonArray).

Concerning "changes on contact type" please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389169/best-practices-for-api-versioning).

Comment: I don't understand how the client can know about the "contact" type.  So I will still need a Contact class defined in my client app correct?

Answer (score 3):

Using the SOAP based WCF bindings, the client would normally generate a client off the WSDL, which would specify these custom types.

*However* as far as I know, in the REST based world of Web API, there is no facility for doing that. It is expected that the 3rd party customer / programmer making the client is given the data contract in some other form, and makes a compatible class.

In other words, there is not really an automatic way of doing that.