# API Versioning for Rails Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, versioning

I'm trying to version my API like Stripe has. Below is given the latest API version is 2.

`/api/users` returns a 301 to `/api/v2/users`

`/api/v1/users` returns a 200 of users index at version 1

`/api/v3/users` returns a 301 to `/api/v2/users`

`/api/asdf/users` returns a 301 to `/api/v2/users`

So that basically anything that doesn't specify the version links to the latest unless the specified version exists then redirect to it.

This is what I have so far:

```
scope 'api', :format => :json do
  scope 'v:api_version', :api_version => /[12]/ do
    resources :users
  end

  match '/*path', :to => redirect { |params| "/api/v2/#{params[:path]}" }
end
```

Answer (score 288, accepted):

[The original form of this answer is wildly different, and can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9627796/2). Just proof that there's more than one way to skin a cat.

I've updated the answer since to use namespaces and to use 301 redirects -- rather than the default of 302. Thanks to pixeltrix and Bo Jeanes for the prompting on those things.

---

You might want to wear a *really* strong helmet because this is going to **blow your mind**.

The Rails 3 routing API is super wicked. To write the routes for your API, as per your requirements above, you need just this:

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :users
  end

  namespace :v2 do
    resources :users
  end
  match 'v:api/*path', :to => redirect("/api/v2/%{path}")
  match '*path', :to => redirect("/api/v2/%{path}")
end
```

If your mind is still intact after this point, let me explain.

First, we call `namespace` which is super handy for when you want a bunch of routes scoped to a specific path and module that are similarly named. In this case, we want all routes inside the block for our `namespace` to be scoped to controllers within the `Api` module and all requests to paths inside this route will be prefixed with `api`. Requests such as `/api/v2/users`, ya know?

Inside the namespace, we define two more namespaces (woah!). This time we're defining the "v1" namespace, so all routes for the controllers here will be inside the `V1` module inside the `Api` module: `Api::V1`. By defining `resources :users` inside this route, the controller will be located at `Api::V1::UsersController`. This is version 1, and you get there by making requests like `/api/v1/users`.

Version 2 is only a *tiny* bit different. Instead of the controller serving it being at `Api::V1::UsersController`, it's now at `Api::V2::UsersController`. You get there by making requests like `/api/v2/users`.

Next, a `match` is used. This will match all API routes that go to things like `/api/v3/users`.

This is the part I had to look up. The `:to =>` option allows you to specify that a specific request should be redirected somewhere else -- I knew that much -- but I didn't know how to get it to redirect to somewhere else and pass in a piece of the original request along with it.

To do this, we call the `redirect` method and pass it a string with a special-interpolated `%{path}` parameter. When a request comes in that matches this final `match`, it will interpolate the `path` parameter into the location of `%{path}` inside the string and redirect the user to where they need to go.

Finally, we use another `match` to route all remaining paths prefixed with `/api` and redirect them to `/api/v2/%{path}`. This means requests like `/api/users` will go to `/api/v2/users`.

I couldn't figure out how to get `/api/asdf/users` to match, because how do you determine if that is supposed to be a request to `/api/<resource>/<identifier>` or `/api/<version>/<resource>`?

Comment: Ryan... I don't think this is actually accurate. This would have /api and /api/v2 serve the same contents instead of having a single canonical URL. /api should redirect to /api/v2 (as the original author specified). I'd expect the correct routes to look something like https://gist.github.com/2044335 (granted, I haven't tested that, though). *Only* /api/v[12] should return a 200, /api and /api/<bad version> should return 301s to /api/v2

Comment: It's worth noting that in the routes file 301 has been made the default redirect and for good reason. From the guides: 

`Please note that this redirection is a 301 “Moved Permanently” redirect. Keep in mind that some web browsers or proxy servers will cache this type of redirect, making the old page inaccessible.`

Comment: If possible it would be nice to be able to return 404 instead of too many redirects as well.

Comment: What is the point of the first match?  If someone requests the v3 api and v2 is the highest, it would make more sense to render a 404 instead.  Also, you can replace `match '*path', :to => redirect("/api/v2/%{path}", :status => 301)` with the simpler form `match '*path' => redirect("/api/v2/%{path}")`.

Comment: Doesn't it create infinite redirects if the path is not correct? For instance, requesting /api/v3/path_that_dont_match_the_routes will create an infinite redirection, right?

Comment: @Robin: Most likely. How would you go about fixing it?

Comment: I think this is broken in the most recent version of Rails 3: I tried it an it caused infinite redirects. I posted a question, then my solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15755981/458968

Comment: Great implementation of versioning. It renders a redirect in HTMl, though, while APIs are written for JSON or XML.

Comment: @shime: Really? The redirect should be handled by other routes in `config/routes.rb`. Do you have an example app that does this that I can poke + prod at?

Comment: Yup :( Sure. There you go: https://gist.github.com/shime/6129865

Sorry for the late response, I had to poke with it myself :P

Comment: The last paragraph is definitely what I was looking for... Makes sense now that you cannot name the API version `android`, `ios` or `angular` to manage multiple kind of APIs using versioning...

Answer (score 38):

A couple of things to add:

Your redirect match isn't going to work for certain routes - the `*api` param is greedy and will swallow up everything, e.g. `/api/asdf/users/1` will redirect to `/api/v2/1`. You'd be better off using a regular param like `:api`. Admittedly it won't match cases like `/api/asdf/asdf/users/1` but if you have nested resources in your api it's a better solution.

Ryan WHY U NO LIKE `namespace`? :-), e.g:

```
current_api_routes = lambda do
  resources :users
end

namespace :api do
  scope :module => :v2, &current_api_routes
  namespace :v2, &current_api_routes
  namespace :v1, &current_api_routes
  match ":api/*path", :to => redirect("/api/v2/%{path}")
end
```

Which has the added benefit of versioned and generic named routes. One additional note - the convention when using `:module` is to use underscore notation, e.g: `api/v1` not 'Api::V1'. At one point the latter didn't work but I believe it was fixed in Rails 3.1.

Also, when you release v3 of your API the routes would be updated like this:

```
current_api_routes = lambda do
  resources :users
end

namespace :api do
  scope :module => :v3, &current_api_routes
  namespace :v3, &current_api_routes
  namespace :v2, &current_api_routes
  namespace :v1, &current_api_routes
  match ":api/*path", :to => redirect("/api/v3/%{path}")
end
```

Of course it's likely that your API has different routes between versions in which case you can do this:

```
current_api_routes = lambda do
  # Define latest API
end

namespace :api do
  scope :module => :v3, &current_api_routes
  namespace :v3, &current_api_routes

  namespace :v2 do
    # Define API v2 routes
  end

  namespace :v1 do
    # Define API v1 routes
  end

  match ":api/*path", :to => redirect("/api/v3/%{path}")
end
```

Comment: How would you deal with the final case? i.e. `/api/asdf/users?` as well as `/api/users/1`? I couldn't figure that out in my updated answer, so figured that you might know of a way

Comment: No easy way to do it - you'd have to define all the redirects before the catch all but you'd only need to do each for each parent resource, e.g. /api/users/*path => /api/v2/users/%{path}

Answer (score 13):

If at all possible, I would suggest rethinking your urls so that the version isn't in the url, but is put into the accepts header.  This stack overflow answer goes into it well:

[Best practices for API versioning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389169/best-practices-for-api-versioning)

and this link shows exactly how to do that with rails routing:

http://freelancing-gods.com/posts/versioning_your_ap_is

Comment: This is an excellent way of doing it also, and would probably cater for the "/api/asdf/users" request as well.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not a big fan of versioning by routes. We built [VersionCake](https://www.github.com/bwillis/versioncake) to support an easier form of API versioning.

By including the API version number in the filename of each of our respective views (jbuilder, RABL, etc), we keep the versioning unobtrusive and allow for easy degradation to support backwards compatibility (e.g. if v5 of the view doesn't exist, we render v4 of the view).

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure why you want to *redirect* to a specific version if a version isn't explicitly requested. Seems like you simply want to define a default version that gets served up if no version is explicitly requested. I also agree with David Bock that keeping versions out of the URL structure is a cleaner way to support versioning.

Shameless plug: Versionist supports these use cases (and more).

https://github.com/bploetz/versionist

Answer (score 3):

Ryan Bigg answer worked for me.

If you also want to keep query parameters through the redirect, you can do it like this:

```
match "*path", to: redirect{ |params, request| "/api/v2/#{params[:path]}?#{request.query_string}" }
```

Answer (score 3):

Implemented this today and found what I believe to be the 'right way' on [RailsCasts - REST API Versioning](http://railscasts.com/episodes/350-rest-api-versioning?view=asciicast). So simple. So maintainable. So effective.

Add `lib/api_constraints.rb` (don't even have to change vnd.example.)

```
class ApiConstraints
  def initialize(options)
    @version = options[:version]
    @default = options[:default]
  end

  def matches?(req)
    @default || req.headers['Accept'].include?("application/vnd.example.v#{@version}")
  end
end
```

Setup `config/routes.rb` like so

```
require 'api_constraints'

Rails.application.routes.draw do

  # Squads API
  namespace :api do
    # ApiConstaints is a lib file to allow default API versions,
    # this will help prevent having to change link names from /api/v1/squads to /api/squads, better maintainability
    scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version:1, default: true) do
      resources :squads do
        # my stuff was here
      end
    end
  end

  resources :squads
  root to: 'site#index'
```

Edit your controller (ie `/controllers/api/v1/squads_controller.rb`)

```
module Api
  module V1
    class SquadsController < BaseController
      # my stuff was here
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can change all links in your app from `/api/v1/squads` to `/api/squads` and you can **EASILY** implement new api versions without even having to change links