# Default Namespace Route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have this route

```
namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
   namespace :v1 do
      post .....
      get .....
   end
end
```

So instead of typing localhost:3000/api/v1/func is there a way to make the v1 defaulted (by routes) which then all I have to type is localhost:3000/api/func?

This way if I come out with api v2, all I have to do is change the route in one place.

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627546/api-versioning-for-rails-routes/9627796#9627796/)

Comment: @xnm thanks. I will defiantly look at that.

Comment: When I curl, I only get back You are being redirected. How do I get my data and not that message? Is is some argument on curl you have to put to allow redirects?

Comment: Yes, that did fix that. But it loses the arguments. What arguments do I add to retain the arguments...like token=1234? Thanks.

Comment: `-d "token=1234` is the argument you pass.

Comment: I think this provides what you're after: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627546/api-versioning-for-rails-routes/9627796#9627796

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're eventually going to release a new API, then in all likelyhood the routes will probably be different, and the code that calls the routes will probably end up being different too.

I would prefer to take the approach of passing the API version with the request, and then responding accordingly. Depending on the structure of your API, could could just need an API version with the first request, and then the rest would use that, via being saved in a session, etc. This is how long-standing APIs such as Paypal work.

Saying that, if you want to do it, this question provides a way: [API Versioning for Rails Routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627546/api-versioning-for-rails-routes/9627796#9627796)