# Redirect /api/v1 to /api/v2 in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, ruby-on-rails-6, api-versioning

I have a Rails 6 app, where I am upgrading some functionalities and upgrading the API version to `v2`. There are older clients out there that are using the `v1` API versions. For all these, I have to change the incoming url in `v1` to `v2`.

Example,
a request comes in at `/api/v1/users`, I want it to change to `/api/v2/users`.

I've tried few things like using `redirect` in `routes.rb` file, like the ones suggested in [API Versioning for Rails Routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627546/api-versioning-for-rails-routes). However, I could not get it too work.

My routes.rb file contains something like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 namespace 'ads' do
  get '/fingerprint' => 'fingerprint#index'
 end

 namespace 'api' do
   scope '/v2' do
     ...
   end
 end

end
```

I'd like to add something like

```
namespace 'api' do

   scope '/v1' do
     # redirect to v2 version of the url 
   end

   scope '/v2' do
     ...
   end
 end
```

I'd like to fix it within the Rails app, but I guess fixing at Apache is also an option. I'm open to any sorts of solutions. Thanks.

Comment: Can you share an example route for the v1 and v2 scopes?

Comment: You can probally use a catch-all such as 'get '*', { |path_params, req|  ... }`. Not sure its actually a good idea to automatically forward clients as it breaks the whole idea of a versioned API which is that the responses should stay consistent within a version until its discontued. A redirect will also break any client thats not configured to follow redirects anyways. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection

Comment: Using something like ['/v1','/v2'].each do |current_scope| scope current_scope do ... seems to work. I don't really see any downsides to it.