# How can I route based on the value of the HTTP Accept header?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm starting to work with the ASP.NET MVC 4 Web API tools and I'd like to version my services using a parameter on the MIME type in the HTTP Accept header in manner similar to what's discussed here: [Best practices for API versioning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389169/best-practices-for-api-versioning)

I've tried a route constraint, but it feels like I'm going down the wrong road. Has anyone else already solved this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A route constraint is the 'right' road, inasfar as it's a way that works to do it.

If you feel like that's a little too hacky, you can always write your own HTTP module and handle the request higher up.