# Is it possible to extend WebMvcConfigurationSupport and use WebMvcAutoConfiguration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I need to extend the WebMvcConfigurationSupport class too modify two things:

```java
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    @Override
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping = super.requestMappingHandlerMapping();
        handlerMapping.setRemoveSemicolonContent(false);
        handlerMapping.setOrder(1);
        return handlerMapping;
    }
}
```

I like the defaults that are registered from the WebMvcAutoConfiguration class but due to the conditional annotation on the class, when I extend the WebMvcConfigurationSupport class it prevents the auto configuration from happening.

```java
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnWebApplication
@ConditionalOnClass({ Servlet.class, DispatcherServlet.class,
    WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.class })
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.class)
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 10)
@AutoConfigureAfter(DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.class)
public class WebMvcAutoConfiguration {...}
```

Is there to have the WebMvcAutoConfiguration class load without having to essentially copy/paste most of the code in that class?

Or is it possible to call RequestMappingHandlerMapping setOrder() and setRemoveSemicolonContent() from somewhere else so I can just use the @EnableWebMvc annotation and have the autoconfiguration class run without any issues?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your analysis is correct (`@EnableWebMvc` or directly extending `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` will switch off the `WebMvcAutoConfiguration`). I'm not sure what the alternative is, since a) we need a "get-out" clause for the autoconfig, and b) I don't think Spring likes to have two `WebMvcConfigurationSupports` in the same context. Happy to discuss on github if you want to try and find a way to change it (there might be some middle ground).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Dave! I'm still a bit green with Spring Boot (Spring in general tbh) ... I started down the road of just creating a new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping bean since I noticed the DispatchServlet grabs all the beans of type HandlerMapping, but I got a little turned around creating the ResourceHttpRequestHandler, and put things down for a bit.

I'll see if I can find something a little less hacky and either throw it here or on Github, maybe an easier way of injecting and ordering the HandlerMapping beans, I'll have to poke at it for a bit. Thanks!

Comment: For your specific narrow use case here I think it would suffice to add a `@Bean` of type `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` (copying the code from `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`). You would need it to have a lower order than the default one (which begs the question: why you use order=1 in your custom mapping?).

Comment: I've been challenging myself on that question as well. My use case involves mapping undetermined requests to a "catch-all" ant-style mapping, e.g., /** The intent was that any mapping with a higher specificity would be mapped first, which is the case for annotated controllers, but is not the case for resource handlers. The goal was to push the resource handlers down a level of precedence below the annotated controllers without losing the /** style mapping. I've been playing with the @Bean idea for the handler mapping actually, so I think that's the right way to go, thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Extend from `DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration` instead of `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`, it will not prevent the autoconfig to take place:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration {
    @Override
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping = super.requestMappingHandlerMapping();
        handlerMapping.setRemoveSemicolonContent(false);
        handlerMapping.setOrder(1);
        return handlerMapping;
    }
}
```

Comment: its ignoring my auto-configs..not sure how its worked for others

Answer (score 9):

I managed to customize the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` while keeping `WebMvcAutoConfiguration` using a BeanPostProcessor:

```
@Configuration
public class RequestMappingConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerMappingPostProcessor requestMappingHandlerMappingPostProcessor() {
        return new RequestMappingHandlerMappingPostProcessor();
    }

    public static class RequestMappingHandlerMappingPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

        @Override
        public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
            if (bean instanceof RequestMappingHandlerMapping) {
                ((RequestMappingHandlerMapping) bean).setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
            }
            return bean;
        }

        @Override
        public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
            return bean;
        }
    }
}
```

I would be happy if Spring Boot provides a better way to handle that... maybe something could be done around `PathMatchConfigurer` ?

Comment: I have found that this solution works in the case where there is  SpringFox Swagger Docket defined in the application . The solution above using the DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration causes the swagger doc display to fail .

Comment: Nice solution. But could you not just directly declare `RequestMappingHandlerMappingPostProcessor` as `@Configuration` here ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this in Spring Boot now is to add a `WebMvcRegistrations` component to your context - this solution didn't exist at the time of your question (it's been available since Spring Boot 1.4.0).

Comment: this is still very limited in case of Exception Handlers as it allows to override only ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver, the one we are interested are the default ones added after.