# Issue with Static resources when extending Spring Boot WebMvcConfigurationSupport

Tags: static, spring-boot, resources

I extended WebMvcConfigurationSupport to implement an api versioning scheme - i.e.

```
@Configuration
public class ApiVersionConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        return new ApiVersionRequestMappingHandlerMapping(readDateToVersionMap());
    }}
```

This uses a custom handler mapping to version the api and works quite nicely.

However it also seems to disable the @EnableAutoConfiguration bean so that now static resources aren't served (as mentioned in this question [Is it possible to extend WebMvcConfigurationSupport and use WebMvcAutoConfiguration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22267191/is-it-possible-to-extend-webmvcconfigurationsupport-and-use-webmvcautoconfigurat)).

Ok, I thought, let's just add a resource handler to the class above - i.e.

```
@Configuration
public class ApiVersionConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("classpath:/public/").addResourceLocations("/");
    }

    @Override
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        return new ApiVersionRequestMappingHandlerMapping(readDateToVersionMap());
    }}
```

However.. this isn't working..? I get this error when I browse to /index.html:

```
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/index.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
```

..If I disable this class then these resources are served just fine by @EnableAutoConfiguration magic.

I've been playing with various options to serve static content having extended the WebMvcConfigurationSupport and thus far no success.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same problem and came up with a solution that just works for me. If you just want to get the resources working without worrying of repetition you can do:

```
@Configuration
public class StaticResourcesConfig extends WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter {

}
```

and then

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@Import(StaticResourcesConfig.class)
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    ...
}
```

This successfully uses the Spring Boot defaults for serving static resources, as long as you don't map `/**` in your controllers.