# How to autowire an implementer with an specific profile in spring?

Tags: java, spring, autowired, spring-profiles

let me demonstrate with code :

```
public interface A {
  ....
}

@Profile({"V1"})
@Component
public class B implements A {
....
}

@Profile({"V2"})
@Component
public class C implements A {
....
}
```

How can i dynamically (on every request that arrives) make spring to autowire one of above classes according to their profile? is it even possible to do such a thing at wiring time?

background : i am seeking a good practice to implement server side version control mechanism. if a request belongs to version 'V1' i want to autowire a class with 'V1' profile and vice versa. (currently i am autowiring a list and iterating  them to find the suitable version).

Comment: No, this is not possible. The spring beans are created at server startup.  You will need to rethink your implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it even possible to autowire bean in every request?

No it's not possible. Beans are injected when the context is created.

> I am seeking a good practice to implement server side version control mechanism

You can follow this answer [How to manage REST API versioning with spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20198275/how-to-manage-rest-api-versioning-with-spring)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is No, because when you try to activate multiple profiles in spring like  `-Dspring.profiles.active=profile1,profile2`and both profiles contains bean that `implements A` then spring will use the last active definition of the bean that `implements A` i.e. `B` in your case.

Comment: If two beans are found, a `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException` is thrown.

Comment: It is thrown thrown when a `BeanFactory` is asked for a bean instance for which multiple matching candidates have been found when only one matching bean was expected.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what would be the case, when both profiles are active (multiple candidates would be found). Of course, if the injection point is a collection, both instances would be injected in the collection, otherwise the said exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface A {
  ....
}

@Profile({"V1"})
@Service("bean1")
public class B implements A {
....
}

@Profile({"V2"})
@Service("bean2")
public class C implements A {
....
}
```

now the third class:

```
class D {
@Autowired
@Qualifier("bean1")
private A a;

}
```

i hope to help you

Comment: This does not answer the question.  @MoienGK wants to load different beans depending on the request payload.

Comment: i thinks that there are not solution for this problem

Answer (score -2):

you use @Qualifier annotation where you want to inject above interface

Comment: thanks. can you add code sample to your answer please?