# Best practice to set api version in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, model-view-controller

I'm working on a small spring mvc project which requires to add api version to the request urls for example: `http://host.serice.com/api/1.0/documents`. As my understanding i can implement like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/api/1.0")
public class DocumentController {
}
```

In my opinion, it's not a good idea because i have to hard code the version number to all controllers, once the version number increase i have to reupdate the controllers again, this work may violate "open for extension closed for modification" principle. Do you have any idea for this ?

Comment: Do you use any build tool like Maven or Gradle? How is your version managed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to manage REST API versioning with spring?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20198275/how-to-manage-rest-api-versioning-with-spring)

Comment: You can use property placeholders in request mappinng, e.g. `"/api/${api.version}"` so you don't have to hardcode anything if that's your concern.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you end up approaching the versioning of your API?