# Spring boot & Swagger 2 UI & custom requestmappinghandlermapping - mapping issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-maven-plugin

I have own RequestMappingHandlerMapping and I am using springfox-swagger-ui. After adding my custom mapping, I am not able to achieve swagger ui at http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html. 
Any ideas?

This is my configuration.

```
    @Configuration
       public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    @Override
    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        return new ApiVersionRequestMappingHandlerMapping("v");
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
          .addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
          .addResourceLocations("(META-INF/resources/webjars");
    }
}
```

Here's my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I finally find it!
The right configuration is this:

```
@Configuration
public class VersioningMappingHandlerConfig {

    @Bean
    public ApiVersionRequestMappingHandlerMapping customMappingHandlerMapping() {
        ApiVersionRequestMappingHandlerMapping handler = new ApiVersionRequestMappingHandlerMapping("v", 1, 1);
        handler.setOrder(-1);
        return handler;
    }

}
```

Note: there is no `extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport` and bean name is `customMappingHandlerMapping`

Comment: Actually this is not correct. If you see my answer (the complete history of my answer) you will see that this is exactly the code I posted as the first idea I suggested but then I explained why this doesn't work. This just registers another HandlerMapping before the default handler mapping. As soon as you put a web method with same @RequestMapping but different versions you will get an error for "ambiguous mapping".

Answer (score 4):

When you override WebMvcConfigurationSupport, you are also overriding spring Boot's mvc auto configuration (WebMvcAutoConfiguration). Therefore, resources that need spring boot's configuration will not work. This is not a problem specific to swagger.

You can find more info about this here:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5004

As the github issue suggests, there will be changes on this in the future to make it easier. Currently there are some workarounds, as suggested there.

A quick and dirty way of doing this is by copying and pasting the WebMvcAutoConfiguration class into your own class, returning your own HandlerMapping from the requestMappingHandlerMapping() method of EnableWebMvcConfiguration and registering the copy of the WebMvcAutoConfiguration as an auto configuration class. You can see instructions here:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html

Make sure you place your copy of the WebMvcAutoConfiguration at some package which is not component scanned and picked up automatically. It should just be registered as explained in the above link.

Also make sure you set the order of you custom HandlerMapping to 0 before returning it from the requestMappingHandlerMapping() method, like so:

```
@Bean
@Primary
@Override
public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
    // Must be @Primary for MvcUriComponentsBuilder to work

    ApiVersionRequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping = new ApiVersionRequestMappingHandlerMapping("v");
    handlerMapping.setOrder(0);
    handlerMapping.setInterceptors(getInterceptors());
    handlerMapping.setContentNegotiationManager(mvcContentNegotiationManager());

    PathMatchConfigurer configurer = getPathMatchConfigurer();
    if (configurer.isUseSuffixPatternMatch() != null) {
        handlerMapping.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(configurer.isUseSuffixPatternMatch());
    }
    if (configurer.isUseRegisteredSuffixPatternMatch() != null) {
        handlerMapping.setUseRegisteredSuffixPatternMatch(configurer.isUseRegisteredSuffixPatternMatch());
    }
    if (configurer.isUseTrailingSlashMatch() != null) {
        handlerMapping.setUseTrailingSlashMatch(configurer.isUseTrailingSlashMatch());
    }
    if (configurer.getPathMatcher() != null) {
        handlerMapping.setPathMatcher(configurer.getPathMatcher());
    }
    if (configurer.getUrlPathHelper() != null) {
        handlerMapping.setUrlPathHelper(configurer.getUrlPathHelper());
    }

    return handlerMapping;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It works for me.
Overriding addResourceHandlers instead of registering auto-configuration.

[Github Source](https://github.com/mspapant/restVersioningExample/)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableSwagger2
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
          registry
            .addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
          registry
            .addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you extend `DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration` then also invoke `super.addResourceHandlers(registry);`.

Comment: WebMvcConfigurerAdapter was deprecated.  Is there a new way to get this working?

Comment: @pitchblack408 `WebMvcConfigurer`'s Javadoc says: *{@code @EnableWebMvc}-annotated configuration classes may implement this interface to be called back and given a chance to customize the default configuration.* so you probably just have to `implements WebMvcConfigurer` instead of `extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`.

Answer (score 3):

Overriding `requestMappingHandlerMapping()` of `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` will turn off spring boot's auto configuration. For adding custom MVC Components you may use WebMvcRegistrations. Like, for providing custom `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`, We may override `getRequestMappingHandlerMapping()`, with custom  `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`, of`WebMvcRegistrationsAdapter` and provide it through `webMvcRegistrationsHandlerMapping()`. As,

```
@Configuration
class CustomRequestMappingHandlerMapping {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcRegistrationsAdapter webMvcRegistrationsHandlerMapping() {
        return new WebMvcRegistrationsAdapter() {
            @Override
            public RequestMappingHandlerMapping getRequestMappingHandlerMapping() {
                return new ApiVersionRequestMappingHandlerMapping("v");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Spring Boot 2.0.0, there is a simpler way to achieve this.

Create an instance of `WebMvcRegistrations` interface as a bean and override appropriate method to return the customized version of that object. Spring boot will read and use that instance.

In this case only the `getRequestMappingHandlerMapping()` needs to be overridden and a custom implementation returned

Above information is from a follow through based on the links provided by @Nazaret K. 
More information at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5004

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved by using WebMvcConfigurationSupport with adding resource handlers for swagger:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    @Value("${spring.application.name}")
    private String applicationName;

    //...irrelevant code here

    @Override
    protected void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
}
```