# Multiple Resource URL in @ApplicationPath

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, rest, restful-url

I have an application which exposes multiple endpoints.
example:

```
v1/transaction/spectra 
v1/transaction/jupiter 
v2/payment/blaze
```

Here is the definition of Application URI

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/v1")
@Component
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

}

@Path("/transaction")
public interface SpectrAPI {
    
    @POST
    @Path("/spectra")
    Response evaluatePlanningDecisions(final Request request); 
 
}

@Path("/transaction")
public interface JupiterAPI {
    
    @POST
    @Path("/jupiter")
    Response evaluatePlanningDecisions(final Request request); 
 
}
```

As the application supports different URL's as shown below

> v1/transaction , v2/payment

How would @ApplicationPath support multiple resourses (v1/v2)?

Comment: Perhaps `@ApplicationPath("/")` and having the version in resource paths? That doesn't seem right to me though, so I might just create two `Application` classes, one for each version.

Comment: maybe you can read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20198275/how-to-manage-rest-api-versioning-with-spring

Comment: @ernest_k When I start the server, all the requests are getting redirected to V2. any reasons?

Comment: @mitali With the current setup? Or did you change it? Also, how are you `Application` classes discovered? Is your jax-rs implementation scanning annotations? Or are you using web.xml config?