# Spring Boot route prefix per folder

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I want to give my routes a prefix based on the folder in which they're in. For example, with this folder structure:

```
controllers/
├─ v1/
│  ├─ Controller.kt
├─ v2/
│  ├─ Controller.kt
```

I would like to get the following routes:

```
{host}/v1/{route}
{host}/v2/{route}
```

Currently, I need to set the 'prefix' on every controller separately:

```kotlin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v2/route")
```

Is there any way to achieve this in Spring with either custom annotations that allow a prefix (`@RestControllerV1("/route")`), or with some setting that just prefixes all files within a specific folder?

Comment: You have to create your own `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`

Comment: @Katy Ok thanks. Any example you can post?

Comment: @KittyCat This has already been answered. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20198275/how-to-manage-rest-api-versioning-with-spring