# Ajax getJSON call is successful but is undefined in IE9

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    console.log(data)
}
```

This code returns undefined for IE9 but is the proper data for IE11, firefox, and chrome. I tried changing it to use $.ajax as well thinking to use the error handler but it never goes there. It returns success. It's just that the data returned is considered undefined.

I've tried cache: false, I've tried removing charset=utf-8 from the content-type. (backend is springMVC). The json being returned is returned programatically so it shouldn't be malformed.

This is quite annoying.

The question is almost exactly the same as: [$.getJSON returning undefined to success callback in IE9 and below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19542146/getjson-returning-undefined-to-success-callback-in-ie9-and-below)

But the accepted answer to that still didn't seem to figure out the root of the issue.
There are a bunch more similar ones as well but none have a good answer.

Comment: When you use ajax what the is the data that is returned? Is it valid Json?

Comment: Yes, it's read and used correctly by all other browsers. I copy pasted it from the network tab and ran it through a linter as well.