# django-rest-framework: api versioning

Tags: python, django, rest, api, django-rest-framework

so googling around it appears that the general consensus is that embedding version numbers in REST URIs is a bad practice and a bad idea.

even on SO there are strong proponents supporting this.
e.g. [Best practices for API versioning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389169/best-practices-for-api-versioning)

My question is about how to accomplish the proposed solution of using the accept header / content negotiation in the django-rest-framework to accomplish this.

It looks like content negotiation in the framework,
http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/content-negotiation/ 
is already configured to automatically return intended values based on accepted MIME types. If I start using the Accept header for custom types, I'll lose this benefit of the framework.

Is there a better way to accomplish this in the framework?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

One way of doing this is to have the versioning specified as part of the media type.

This is what GitHub [currently do for their API](http://developer.github.com/v3/media/).

You can also include media type parameters in your accept headers, eg `Accept: application/json; version=beta`, which will successfully match against `JSONRenderer`.  You can then code your view to behave differently depending on the accepted media type, see [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#varying-behaviour-by-media-type).

There's lots of different patterns for versioning in APIs, and I wouldn't say there's any great consensus around the right approach yet, but that'd be one reasonable possibility.

---

**Update Jan 2015**: Better versioning support will be incoming in the 3.1.0 release. See [this pull request]

**Update March 2015**: Docs for the versioning API [are now available](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/versioning/).

(https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/pull/2285) for more details.

Comment: Apparently this question has earned a popular question badge and just realized i never accepted the answer. Thanks for all your hard work on the framework Tom!

Answer (score 54):

**UPDATE:**

[versioning](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/versioning/) is now properly supported.

---

There are some answers from your link:

> We found it practical and useful to put the version in the URL. It
>   makes it easy to tell what you're using at a glance. We do alias /foo
>   to /foo/(latest versions) for ease of use, shorter / cleaner URLs,
>   etc, as the accepted answer suggests.
>       Keeping backwards compatibility forever is often cost-prohibitive and/or very difficult. We prefer to give advanced notice of
>   deprecation, redirects like suggested here, docs, and other
>   mechanisms.

So we took this approach, plus allowing clients to specify the version in request header (X-Version), here is how we did it:

Structure in side the API app:

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── middlewares.py
├── urls.py
├── v1
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── account
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── serializers.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   └── urls.py
└── v2
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── account
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── serializers.py
    │   └── views.py
    └── urls.py
```

project urls.py:

```
url(r'^api/', include('project.api.urls', namespace='api')),
```

api app level urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'', include('project.api.v2.urls', namespace='default')),
    url(r'^v1/', include('project.api.v1.urls', namespace='v1')),
)
```

version level urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import *
from .account import views as account_views
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('account', account_views.AccountView)
router.register('myaccount', account_views.MyAccountView)
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

create a middleware to switch to the correct code by changing the path_info, please note there is a caveat that namespace ('api') defined in project level urls is not flexible and needs to be known in middleware:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse


class VersionSwitch(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        r = resolve(request.path_info)
        version = request.META.get('HTTP_X_VERSION', False)
        if r.namespace.startswith('api:') and version:
            old_version = r.namespace.split(':')[-1]
            request.path_info = reverse('{}:{}'.format(r.namespace.replace(old_version, version), r.url_name), args=r.args, kwargs=r.kwargs)
```

Sample url:

```
curl -H "X-Version: v1" http://your.domain:8000/api/myaccount/
```

Comment: This approach would be fine, except that it breaks hyperlinked fields (`HyperlinkedRelatedField` etc). Any ideas?

Comment: I haven't got a project setup to use `HyperlinkedRelatedField` I guess your problem would be the link going to the default version if you specified a different version?

Comment: Exactly. I am inclined to go with `Accept` header method of versioning so that URLs don't change at all.

Comment: I am afraid there is no easy way to fix until versioning is baked into the package, so it will produce version aware urls for `HyperlinkedRelatedField`

Comment: ... unless you like monkey patch?

Comment: I don't like monkey patching. But I don't mind forking and adding support for versioned urls.

Comment: What about working without namespaces and not creating the middleware?

Comment: So where do we put the models?

Comment: Your data models will be in your app folder.

Comment: James, do you have one app per version? or one app called "api"  and modules in it? do you mean having separate models per version?

Comment: I have multiple apps with models in it, and one app which is the 'API' which has versions.

Comment: @Mar0ux I fixed `HyperlinkedRelatedField` with making the `SerializerMethodField` and calling `reverse` with, very unobvious, passing extra parameter `current_app` to it. 

For example, I have an app 'fruits_app', with namespace versions 'v1', 'v2'. And I have serializer of Fruit model. So I create a field 

`url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()`

And the reverse call would be like:

`def get_url(self, instance):
    reverse.reverse(''fruits_app:fruit",
        args=[instance.pk],
        request=request,
        current_app=request.version)`

Answer (score 1):

@James Lin gave a great answer. In comments to the answer @Mar0ux asked what to do with broken `HyperlinkedRelatedField` fields.

I fixed this with changing `HyperlinkedRelatedField` to the `SerializerMethodField` and calling `reverse` with, very unobvious, passing extra parameter `current_app` to it.

For example, I have an app 'fruits_app', with namespace versions 'v1', 'v2'. And I have serializer of Fruit model. So to serialize url I create a field

```
url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
```

And corresponding method:

```
def get_url(self, instance):
    reverse.reverse('fruits_app:fruit-detail',
        args=[instance.pk],
        request=request,
        current_app=request.version)
```

With nested namespaces you will need to change add those namespaces to current_app. For example, if you have an app 'fruits_app' with namespace versions 'v1', 'v2', and instance namespace 'bananas' inside the app, method for serializing Fruit url will look like:

```
def get_url(self, instance):
    reverse.reverse('fruits_app:fruit-detail',
        args=[instance.pk],
        request=request,
        current_app='bananas:{}'.format(request.version))
```