# Django REST Framework: How to add prefix in URL for versioning

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

I am trying to create version for REST application. Here is my URL Examle

```
www.myapi.com/foo [default version]
www.myapi.com/v1/foo [version one]
```

This is the project structure

> ```
> ├── __init__.py
> ├── settings.py
> ├── urls.py
> ├── default_app
> │ ├── __init__.py
> │ ├── serializer.py
> │ ├── models.py
> │ ├── views.py
> │ ├── urls.py
> │ 
> └── v1_app
> ├── __init__.py
> ├── serializer.py
> ├── models.py
> ├── views.py
> ├── urls.py
> ```

**default_app urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import *
from default_app import views as df_views
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'foo', df_views.viewname, "foo")
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

**v1_app urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import *
from v1_app import views as ver_views
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'foo', ver_views.viewname, "foo")
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

**main file for urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from defualt_app import urls as default_urls
from v1_app import urls as v1_urls
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns



urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^', include(default_urls, namespace="default")),
    url(r'^v1/', include(v1_urls, namespace="v1"))
)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

My issue is, when i using simple url without any prefix then it is working

> www.myapi.com/foo

and when i used version prefix v1 or v2 then it throws error [Page not found (404)]

> www.myapi.com/v1/foo

I got this idea from this link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21839842/1558544

If I don't use middleware class then is this possible to get same result?

Thank you

Comment: what happends if you place the more explicit '^v1' pattern infront of '^'

Comment: Then both are not going to work.Page not found (404) error

Answer (score 2):

**Django REST Framework does not support url namespaces well**, but there are solutions to making them work for most cases.

In the case of serializers, you must define all fields that are hyperlinked with a `HyperlinkedRelatedField`, including the `url` field that is automatically added, which is a `HyperlinkedIdentityField`. This includes setting the `view_name` argument on all of the fields to the correct, automatically generated view name. This should be something like `[namespace]:[base_name]-detail`.

But this also means **you cannot use the `DefaultRouter` index page** that is generated by the `DefaultRouter`, as it does not handle namespaces at all. In order to get one, you are going to  need to either create your own, or override the automatically generated view in the router.