# Best practice for DRF versioning - copy whole folder? Or subclass previous version?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, versioning

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14269719/django-rest-framework-api-versioning), and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14269719/django-rest-framework-api-versioning/21839842#21839842) in particular, what's the most sustainable way of creating v2, v3, etc - most times, each version introduces incremental changes over the previous version. Most endpoints stay the same, most fields stay the same.

Option 1: Copy v1 folder, redo the internal references to ensure the code is updated, and then make your changes over that. This keeps every version self contained. If a bug shows up, you fix it in all versions. Versions are clean and dependencies are easier to manage. However, you end up with lots of duplicated code after v30, for example.

Option 2: Create v2 folder, and make v2 classes subclass v1 classes, providing the base functionality, and then add your changes. This promotes code re-use, but can get unwieldly very fast, eg. tracing a change/fixing a bug when you have over 30 versions.

Any prevailing best practices, pros/cons?

Comment: If you're moving from v1 to v2 that suggests some big time backwards compatibility breaking change. I'd do them as self contained modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Option 2 will turn into Option 1 in a few versions.

In my opinion there are two cases:

**1 case**: you have traditional mostly-CRUD API and then I would suggest to look at [this post](https://blog.rescale.com/api-versioning-with-the-django-rest-framework/) which shows a way to create a transitions between versions through Serializers.

**2 case**: your API is more about algorithms, logic and data processing - then you can go with Option 1 - create another app in DRF (copy the folder), move all common libraries out of the app and keep only classes that could change and need a backwards compatibility support in the app.

Comment: Thanks for linking to [this post](https://blog.rescale.com/api-versioning-with-the-django-rest-framework/), I ended up using that method.

Comment: You're welcome. I really like this approach. Author also mentions [this article](http://amberonrails.com/move-fast-dont-break-your-api/) which was really inspiring for me as well.