# What should I version while doing an API versioning in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, api-versioning

Currently, I am doing an API versioning for our project. We have 10 apps and 45 API endpoints. Each app has `models`, `tasks`, `utils`, `constants`, `serializers`, `views` and `urls` files. Now, I have created an `apis` app which contains version folder e.g `v1`, `v2` etc. and each version folder contains `serializers`, `views`, `utils` and `urls` files.

Now, I need to know what should I consider for versioning? should I version the `tasks`, `utils` and `constants` also? And how should I do versioning for `models`?

Please guys help me to sort out this.

Comment: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/versioning/

Comment: @wolendranh It just mentioned the ways of `API versioning` but it didn't mention what you should version.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14269719/django-rest-framework-api-versioning please check answers from this topic. There is an example with versioning of apps.

Comment: @wolendranh but still not clear should I version `tasks`, `utils` and `constants` or not.

Comment: but the link is informative. Thanks @wolendranh