# RESTful API: is it good to have foreign key which sends to different version of the API?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

We are developing a RESTful API using **Django REST framework**, and we decided to handle foreign keys showing a URL to the relation's resource, for example:

```
GET https://url_to_api/api/v2/foo/1:

{
    "id": 1,
    "bar": "https://url_to_api/api/v2/bar/6/",
    "baz": "https://url_to_api/api/v3/baz/4/"
}
```

This is a GET request for the **foo's ID 1** on the **version 2** of the API.

Django REST framework returns the URL to the v2 for the relation with the bar entity because `/api/v2/bar/6/` sends to a view which is only used by this version, but it returns an URL to v3 (https://url_to_api/api/v3/baz/4/) for the relation with the baz entity, because its view is the same as the v2's one, and Django REST framework reverse engine returns the first result for the URL which sends to the same view.

**I have a couple of questions about this behaviour:**

- is it a normal behaviour or we are missing or doing something wrong?
- is it good to have URLs which sends to a different version of the API?

Any other ideas on how to manage this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal behaviour in DRF. So either you can specify like this or else you specify custom for everything.

```
# bookings/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', bookings_list, name='bookings-list'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', bookings_detail, name='bookings-detail')
]

# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^v1/bookings/', include('bookings.urls', namespace='v1')),
    url(r'^v2/bookings/', include('bookings.urls', namespace='v2'))
]
```

For further reference, [refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14269719/django-rest-framework-api-versioning)

Comment: Thanks! So do you confirm me that having URLS which go to a different API version is a bad practice?

Comment: It's not like that. You need to specify your views, based on your requirements. If only small different is there in two version. You can have your current solution with small condition.

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to have a "version coherent" behaviour, so having URL to the current version the client is using even if there are no differences, but I just want to understand if it is a good practice, or if it's better to use the default behaviour of DRF.