# How to write rails route to map versioned API with major and minor version in path like /api/v1.2/users/1234

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes

I've read this [Best practices for API versioning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389169/best-practices-for-api-versioning). And I agree with putting the version in url path rather than in HTTP header.

In order to implement this, I have a namespaced controller like this:

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < Api::BaseController
  def show
    ...
  end
end
```

And the route are:

```
current_api_routes = lambda do
  resource :users
end

namespace :api do
  namespace :v1, &current_api_routes
end
```

Then `rake routes` I can get routes like this:

```
api_v1_user GET    /api/v1/users/:id(.:format)                       api/v1/users#show
...
```

I want that version `v1.2` goes to controller of `v1`. Then I can get minor version number in controller like this:

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < Api::BaseController
  def show
    minor_version = params[:minor_version] # minor_version = 2
    ...
  end
end
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: The answer really depends on what you're going to do with this minor version afterwards. What is the purpose of having this?

Comment: I want this to manage both major and minor version of APIs. It means if API get little changes I just bump the minor version, not the major version which was handled by a namespaced controller, so I would not get too many controllers after a few minor changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We are using minor API versioning for small but possibly breaking changes (like allowing `null` values for an attribute that previously wouldn't be allowed to be so).

```
# config/routes.rb
My::Application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    scope "v:api_version", module: "v1", as: "v1", constraints: { api_version: /1(\.[0123]?)/ } do
      resources :users
    end
  end
end

# app/controllers/api/application_controller.rb
class API::ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  private
  def api_version
    @api_version ||= begin
      major, minor = params[:api_version].split('.', 2).map(&:to_i)
      OpenStruct.new(major: major, minor: minor || 0)
    end
  end
end

# app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb
class API::V1::UsersController < API::ApplicationController
  def show
    # ...
    something_more if api_version.minor >= 2
  end
end
```

Comment: I had to do `scope "v(:api_version)"` or I was getting routing errors

Comment: @vedant1811 Thanks! We've been using this in production for 1.5y, on Rails 4.1 and 4.2. It could be Rails-version-dependant, perhaps?