# Should I use the Content-Location header this way?

Tags: http, rest

**Preface:**

After reading a lot about HTTP and REST, you have spent a few hours devising a cunning content-negotiation scheme. So that your web API can serve XML, JSON and HTML from a single URL. Because, you know, a resource should only have one URL and different representations should be requested using `Accept` headers. You start to wonder why it took the web 20 years for that realization.

And that is when reality [slaps you in the face](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/07/01/ie-and-the-accept-header.aspx).

So to help browsers (and yourself trying to debug) with coercing your service to serve the desired content type you do what every self-respecting REST evangelist would despise you for: *Filename extensions.*

**Eternal torment in hell notwithstanding, is the following use of `Content-Location` + `.ext` acceptable?**

Say we have users at `/users/:loginname` for example `/users/bob`. This would be the API endpoint for anything that is capable of setting a proper `Accept` header. But for any possible `Content-Type` (or at least some), we allow an alternate method of access and that is a URL with a filetype suffix. For example `/users/bob.html` for an HTML representation. Let's assume (and that is a big assumption to make) login names will *never* contain a period/dot.

Request:

```
GET /users/bob.json HTTP/1.1  
Host: example.com
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 14
Content-Location: /users/bob

{"foo": "bar"}
```

This would allow me to encode *alternative* ways to access (in this case) the user information.
For example a link to a user page could be `<a href="/users/bob.html">Bob</a>`.
A link to a vCard (to add the user to the Address-Book/Outlook/anything) would be `<a href="/users/bob.vcf">Bob</a>`.

Are there any pitfalls I have missed? What would be pros/cons of this?

Edit: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15473879/1762194) popped up a bit late for me to notice. And even though it touches the subject and is really helpful, I think it's not exactly what I'm looking for...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you use Content-Location exactly the wrong way; it should point to the more specific URI.

Answer (score 0):

According to RFC 2616:

```
The Content-Location entity-header field MAY be used to supply 
the resource location for the entity enclosed in the message 
when that entity is accessible from a location separate from 
the requested resource's URI.
```

and

```
The Content-Location value is not a replacement for the original
requested URI; it is only a statement of the location of the resource 
corresponding to this particular entity at the time of the request.
```

so generally, yes, you can use Content-Location header to identify origin resource. Main disadvantage of using of extension suffix is that you are making another URLs, e.g. /users/bob, /users/bob.vfc, /users/bob.html are three different resources.