# Periods not allowed in CodeIgniter URI?

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, rest, routes

So after reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389169/best-practices-for-api-versioning) on API versioning, I decided to prefix all my routes with a version number:

```
http://localhost/api/1.0/user/login
```

But when I throw an exception within Exceptions Core, it says that the route is:

```
10/UserControll...
```

I've tried escaping the period, but this did not work. Can anyone replicate this problem and think of a possible solution for it?

This is the route I am using for the above:

```
$route['1.0/user/(:any)'] = '1.0/UserController/$1';
```

These are my permitted URI chars:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%\.:_\-';
```

Comment: Can you paste a sample route with the prefix from your routes.php?

Comment: I added an example route.

Comment: What do you mean by throwing an exception within Exceptions core? When I use `$this->uri->uri_string()` in the controller, it shows the URI correctly. I'm not clear on what you're trying to do (and I'm not going to read that HUGE post in the link you added).

Comment: In `system/core/Exceptions.php` I added a `throw new Exception()` to see what route was causing the 404, and it showed a route without a period. I cannot use `uri_string()` in my controller because CodeIgniter never reaches my controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on line 468 of `system/core/Router.php`. Change `set_directory` from this:

```
$this->directory = str_replace(array('/', '.'), '', $dir).'/';
```

To this:

```
$this->directory = str_replace(array('/'), '', $dir).'/';
```

Anyone have a guess or gander as to why the Router removes periods from directory names?

Answer (score 3):

```
Open libraries/Input.php (system/core/Input.php in CI version 2.0+) and locate function _clean_input_keys($str){, The whole block should look like so:

function _clean_input_keys($str)
{
    if ( ! preg_match("/^[a-z0-9:_\/-]+$/i", $str))
    {
        exit('Disallowed Key Characters.');
    }

    return $str;
}
```

Check if this has '.' in the preg_match.
If not add it, so that your regular expression look like this-

```
/^[a-z0-9:_\/-\.]+$/i
```

Comment: This brought me closer to figuring out why this is happening. The problem isn't the route, as I mistakenly said earlier, the problem is the controller path that is losing the period.

Comment: awsumnik, you need to escape "-" symbol if it's not the first or the last in the expression, so the valid regexp is "/^[a-z0-9:_\/.-]+$/i"

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the (.) in your

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
```

And what is your controller name ?

I think you must have the controller name in your route before the method name.

Something like this :

```
$route['controller_name/1.0/user/(:any)'] = ...
```

Comment: Yes, I do have '.' in my permitted URL chars. `User` is the name of my controller. If I change the controller to `1-0/User/$1`, it works, but not with periods.

Comment: It isn't a URL problem. The URL reads the route just fine. It's a period in the controller's path that's breaking it. You can have folders prefix the controller name.