# Getting a 404 error with parameters which contain periods ('.') using jquery .load() function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to call a controller function using the .load() function but I'm getting an error probably because of the '.' encoding. I'm doing the call like this:

```
$("#main-content").load(
   url + "/" + encodeURIComponent(text1) + "/" + encodeURIComponent(text2)
);
```

Everything goes fine except when *text1* ends with a period:

```
var text1 = 'This causes error.';
```

The url is encoded like:

```
http://localhost/index.php/controller/function/This%20causes%20error./Text2
```

And I'm getting a 404 error in the Chrome console, so I suspect that the '.' is breaking the URL.

I've been looking a lot of posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938900/how-to-encode-periods-for-urls-in-javascript), but those solutions doesn't work for me. I'm thinking into create a function that converts the '.' into any other character and then do the opposite in the server, but I prefer to look for something more "elegant" first.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: This is likely not a JS problem, but rather a CodeIgniter issue. See, for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201888/periods-not-allowed-in-codeigniter-uri

Comment: Yes, I had seen that post, but I tried what they suggested and still have the 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using ajax post method

```
  $.ajax({
        url: url+ + "/",
        type: 'POST',

        data: {data1:encodeURIComponent(text1),data2:encodeURIComponent(text2)},

        success: function (data, status)
        {
               $("#main-content").text(data)

        }
    });
});
```

Receive text1 and text2 at your controller  as

```
 $text1=$this->input->post("data1")  
 $text1=$this->input->post("data2")
```

Comment: It worked! I've edited your answer to change the `url + + "/" ` for `url + "/"` and the `.text(data)` for `.html(data)`. Thanks a lot.