# Codeigniter - dots in a controller folder name

Tags: codeigniter

I'm using the latest version of Codeigniter and I try to achieve specific controller folders structure.

I'm would like to create a controller folder for each of my webapp version:

```
/controllers/1.0.0/login (where login is the name of the controller)
/controllers/2.0.0/login (where login is the name of the controller)
```

the problem: it seems Codeigniter working great with controller folders but not working with controller folders that contain dot :(

Like this working good (without dots):

```
/controllers/100/login (where login is the name of the controller)

/controllers/200/login (where login is the name of the controller)
```

Is there a way to make Codeigniter work with dots on controller folders?

Thanks
Shai

Comment: Where are you writing this path? In your config file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201888/periods-not-allowed-in-codeigniter-uri

Answer (score 0):

I also getting the same issue.
You can use like this in your route

**config/route.php**

```
$route['Controller/1.0.0/login'] = 'Controller/100/login';
$route['Controller/2.0.0/login'] = 'Controller/200/login';
```

This is working fine for me