# Rails API versioning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, versioning, api-versioning

I am trying to implement api versioning the Railscasts #350 way (no gem).  Is there a way to create only updated resources in new version and not entire set of controllers and views(jbuilder) with fallback to latest supporting version functionality?
I am using the accept header with "scope model:" without namespaces.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not version only part of a resource e.g. create. What will happen is you'll have dependencies created and your views and controllers only know 1 version of the resource. This can lead into problems in the future. You should do a default version if non is provided.

[Best practices for API versioning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389169/best-practices-for-api-versioning?rq=1)