# How to solve obstacles related to API version

Tags: java, api, restful-architecture, api-versioning

I am having a restfull service and there are more than 20 clients thats is using this service.

```
@Path("/provider")
public class Provider{

@Path("/simpleprovider")
@GET
public String getProvider(){
return "Simple Provider";
}
}
```

Now i have decided to introduce version in service, i have google alot, read my articles but i am totally confused how should i do? suppose i change URI for new service like `@Path("/provider/v1")` than how should i provide support for existing clients ? by considering this thing should i have to provide change on every client whenever api new version comes in action ?

After Googling i found that there are 3 ways to provide versioning

1. URL versioning
2. custom request header
3. content type

but could not find any practical example please help me in this regard

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389169/best-practices-for-api-versioning](http://www.narwhl.com/2015/03/the-ultimate-solution-to-versioning-rest-apis-content-negotiation/)
http://www.narwhl.com/2015/03/the-ultimate-solution-to-versioning-rest-apis-content-negotiation/
http://restcookbook.com/Basics/versioning/

http://www.troyhunt.com/2014/02/your-api-versioning-is-wrong-which-is.html

http://www.lexicalscope.com/blog/2012/03/12/how-are-rest-apis-versioned/

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Versioning a service can be very tricky and is always a big decision when determining the versioning strategy.  Especially if you have people using the service.  From my experience here are some things to consider:

1. Understand and communicate when and if you plan on sun setting versions of your API.  The last thing you want to have is a problem where you are having to upkeep 10 different versions of an API.
2. Understand if a version change is absolutely necessary.  A good rule of thumb is if core functionality is changing or if the contract can potentially break someones software that is integrating with your API.  Here are some things to consider when determining if you really need to version:

   - If you are removing fields from a resource.
   - If you are removing (or updating) a URL (or method).
   - If an existing endpoint (or method) logic is going to change such that it would require a consumer to re-implement.
   - Overall, if a change that you make would break someone integrating with your API.
3. Are you going to require database changes that would not be backwards compatible with your previous version(s)?  This is when versioning can get really fun (sarcastically) because now you might have to make your database backwards compatible which, in my experience, can be difficult problem to deal with moving forward.

To answer your question, though, I have found the best way to version to be in the URL.  Be very simple and deliberate with your versioning so that it is crystal clear for your integrator.  For example:

- GET /v1/products/{id} // Version 1
- GET /v2/products/{id} // Version 2

** If you decide on URL versioning then my advice is to put do "v" for version and a SINGLE number like 1 or 2.  Don't get into versions, sub versions, etc...  This will make your API seem like it revs a lot which can cause concern for consumers.  Also, keep the version as FAR left of the URL as possible.  The idea is that everything to the right of the version is the new versioned resource.
I would AVOID using headers to version your service.  You don't want to hide versions from your consumer.  Be as transparent and explicit about versioning as you possibly can.

Versioning in the URL allows you to also do some useful routing and things on your web server and proxies as well.  You can either version like this in your actual code, for example:

```
[HttpGet("v1/products")]
public Product GetProduct(string id)
{
    return _repository.GetProduct(id);
}
```

or you can version using your web server by setting up virtual directories (or whatever).  Then your code might look something like this instead:

```
[HttpGet("products")]
public Product GetProduct(string id)
{
    return _repository.GetProduct(id);
}
```

However you decide to version it is very important to think about the pro's and con's of each decision and weigh them because if you are running an API that people are using the bad decisions will catch up to you in a hurry.

Comment: Thanks @Jerrod Horton , you mean to say that every time url changes from v1/products to v2/products we have to change the client ??  and how should i do support both versioning v1 and v2 ? how google,youtube,facebook versioning api works?

Comment: No problem.What I am saying is that if you use the url to version and you roll out a new version, your clients do NOT have to change (provided you are supporting your previous version).Because the url goes from /v1/products (which is being used and still supported) to /v2/products, that means that people using the /v1/products will be unaffected by the new version you introduce for /v2/products. Now this is only true, of course, if the code you write for your version 2 does not cause version 1 to break.  How do you manage multiple versions of an API is a much broader (and trickier) of a topic

Comment: @ Jerrod Hortan my point is cleared now ,but one thing i want to know is when we introduce  new version it means that there well be separate class for it to support new version with new version signature ?? If yes it means that if you have 5 different versions than there will be 5 different classes  for it ?

Comment: Yes.  In my experience it is best to not only have 5 different classes for 5 different versions but, sometimes, it is even good to have completely separate projects for them.  The risk you run of having them all in the same project is that you might accidentally change something on a previous version without meaning to because of something you needed to add for a current version.  However, I would say to keep them in different classes at the very least.