# What's the best way to handle android and apple mobile app upgrades?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, google-play

I have read the app version control docs on both google and apple official websites but still have the following questions :

1. Google does not specify a particular time when the updated app would be available for download  to users - how do I decide when to deploy updates to my web services? If I deploy the web services before the app is available then the app will be hitting the old web service and give an error, vice versa also the app will hit an incorrect web service and give an error. How can I time this efficiently.
2. The strategy that my team has come up with is to return back the app version every time a web service call is made, if the version number differs from the back end then the user will get a message saying "please update your app" and clicking okay will take them to the play store - here is there a way I can directly download the app on the phone when the user clicks okay instead of the user having to search for the app in the play store?

Are there any standard practices that apps around the world follow for updates?

Comment: You could version your API, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389169/best-practices-for-api-versioning

Comment: Okay so my concern is not how to version my API but how to time the client and server side changes? Since both deploy via different channels and there is no confirmation of when the app would be available to users.