# Proxy API paths

Tags: proxy, koa

I'm building an API using [KOA](http://koajs.com) and have read some best practise on versioning. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389169/best-practices-for-api-versioning) pointed out that versions should be hidden from the client.

My question is, how would I go about doing this? I've read some mentions of using an API proxy. Would I be using something like "Squid" as a reverse-proxy, or are there better Node/KOA specific solutions for this type of work?

Answer (score 0):

I think GraphQL is the perfect tool to avoid pain in the ass with API.
Yes, in some point it breaks the REST philosophy but gives flexibility.

All you need to build a flexible API with no worry about version is: **Koa**, **Objection** + **GraphQL**.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll look into it.