# What is benefit of aspnet-api-versioning?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, versioning, asp.net-web-api-routing

With routing done by controller name (unless route set for each controller/action), I see the only benefit of using the ApiVersion attribute in having versioned APIs use the same controller name but in separate namespaces.

Otherwise the proper use that I have found is:

```
[ApiVersion("2.0"]
[RoutePrefix("api/v{version:apiVersion}/test")]
```

I do not see any efficiency or productiviy gain here when this must be applied across the board, there is no difference in dropping the package and simply using this:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v2.0/test")]
```

I can only assume that I am missing something obvious here.

Comment: The following link may help you to understand the concept
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/22217668](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22217668)

Answer (score 1):

There is a laundry list of *benefits*; far too many to all list here. Here's an attempt to cover some of the most common, high-level benefits:

- An *API Version* is a first-class type and not a *magic* string. `2.0` and `2` are semantically equivalent; therefore, `api/v2.0/test` and `api/v2/test` are the same resource.
- You do **not** have to use attributes. This one of several ways to you can apply API versions. You can also use *conventions*.
- There is a built-in convention to support an implicit API version derived from the containing source code namespace.
- Multiple versioning styles are supported (query string, URL segment, header, media type) or you can plug-in your own method.
- API version to method mapping. A single controller might support multiple API versions, which is referred to as *version interleaving*. You can map different action methods to be called on a single controller type, while defining a single route template. (ex: `1.0` might map to `GetV1` and `2.0` might map to `GetV2`).
- API version *advertisement*, which gives a way for you to inform your clients which API versions are supported and/or deprecated per API.
- API Explorer support, which collates your APIs by version and be used with Swagger/OpenAPI documents, etc.