# Hosting multiple product APIs in single ASP.NET Core WebAPI Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.2

I am designing an ASP.NET Core based Web API, which needs to support multiple variants of my product, let's say based on a license or the variety which it was installed.

Instead of going for multiple services for each type of product, I thought of a single service which houses/hosts multiple Endpoints or URLs. I will make this configurable in the appsettings.json at the time of installation.

I am aware of the [UseUrls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-2.2#server-urls) on creating the WebHost, but can I bind the specific URL in a set of URLs to specific Controllers?

Code:

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.UseUrls("http://localhost:5000;http://localhost:5001;https://localhost:5002")
```

Expect

```
https://localhost:5000/ --> Product1Controller
https://localhost:5001/ --> Product2Controller
https://localhost:5002/ --> Product2Controller
```

I am new to the ASP.NET Core, please help me if this is achievable or not. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should use only one endpoint and the variants of product is just a property of your model [api-design](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/api-design)

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389169/best-practices-for-api-versioning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workaround is to add custom Constraint on api controller which is enabled with specific port.

1.Create  a `PortActionConstraint` class:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class PortActionConstraint : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
    public PortActionConstraint(int port)
    {
        Port = port;
    }

    public int Port { get; }

    public override bool IsValidForRequest(RouteContext routeContext, ActionDescriptor action)
    {
        //external port
        var externalPort = routeContext.HttpContext.Request.Host.Port;
        //local port 
        var localPort = routeContext.HttpContext.Connection.LocalPort;
        //write here your custom logic. for example  
        return Port == localPort;
    }
}
```

2.Add attribute with correspond port number on all controller like

```
[PortActionConstraint(5000)]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class Product1Controller : ControllerBase
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Now I am making another way using your solution :)