# Accessing Configuration Properties for the Class Decorators in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2.2

Based on this [Question Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56288153/hosting-multiple-product-apis-in-single-asp-net-core-webapi-service/) , I am working on the solution to bind the controllers to certain **URLs**. These URLs are configured in `appsettings.json`.

As the solution is based on the Decorators, I am searching for a way to inject the IConfiguration object for the decorators.

**Example :**

```
[PortActionConstraint(configuration.GetValue<string>("Product1:Port")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class Product1Controller : ControllerBase
```

In short, how can I inject IConfiguration of any Interface to the Class Decorator ?

Comment: Have you seen the [`ServiceFilterAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.servicefilterattribute?view=aspnetcore-2.2)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution for this is to use the service locator pattern inside of your constraint implementation to retrieve the `IConfiguration` object.

So within the ´IsValidForRequest` method, retrieve the service through the HTTP context:

```
public override bool IsValidForRequest(RouteContext routeContext, ActionDescriptor action)
{
    var configuration = routeContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IConfiguration>();

    // do something with the configuration
}
```

Alternatively, you could also implement the [`IActionConstraintFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actionconstraints.iactionconstraintfactory?view=aspnetcore-2.2) which would allow you to properly resolve the dependencies using constructor injection. This will require you to implement the `IActionConstraint` yourself though. So for this simple requirement, using the `ActionMethodSelectorAttribute` with the service locator is probably easier.

Comment: Thanks Poke. I was fiddling with the DI in the Attribute's Constructor, now I am able to proceed with the your solution.

Comment: RE your edit suggestion: `GetService<T>` is not deprecated. You may need to add a using for the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` namespace to make it compile.