# How to implement api versioning?

Tags: api, versioning

I have an web API application that will serve many clients at different times of release and now i need to implement a versioning. Because the API code will be constantly updated and API users will not be able to instantly change their API. Well, the standard situation is when you need to introduce versioning in general. I'm finding a way to organize it inside my API. It's clear that it will not be different folders with an application on the server, conditionally called app_v1, app_v2, app_v2.1, etc., cause this is duplication, redundancy and bad practise.
It's look like will be one application, and in the controllers at the code level there will be a division of the logic already, like `If(client_version==1) do function1() else if(client_version==2) do function2(), etc`. It seems that git supports tags, this is something similar to versioning, but because all supported versions of the application need be on the server at the same time, this is not about that. how i can realize an architecture in this case?

Comment: You might want to have read through this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389169/best-practices-for-api-versioning

Answer (score 0):

There are many well-known ways to use API versioning to make code work with older versions. (backward compatibility). The general purpose of API versioning is a way to make sure that different clients can use different versions of an API at the same time. I've seen several ways to do API versioning, such as:

URL Path Versioning: In this method, the number of the version is part of the API endpoint's URL path. For instance:

```
https://api.example.com/v1/assets
https://api.example.com/v2/assets
```

URL Query String Parameter: In this method, the version number is added to the API endpoint's URL as a query string parameter. For instance:

```
https://api.example.com/assets?version=1
https://api.example.com/assets?version=2
```

HTTP Header: In this method, the version number is put in an HTTP header, like the `Accept-Version` header. For instance:

```
Accept-Version: 1
Accept-Version: 2
```

If you are using dotnet for you project I would like recommend to standard library for that recommend to check this [out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/visual-studio-toolbox/versioning-aspnet-core-services). Or you can find solid materials in term of WebApi Versioning following [link](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/aspdotnet-core-6-web-api-best-practices?aid=7010a000002LUv2AAG&promo=&utm_source=non_branded&utm_medium=digital_paid_search_google&utm_campaign=XYZ_EMEA_Dynamic&utm_content=&cq_cmp=1576650371&gclid=CjwKCAiAkrWdBhBkEiwAZ9cdcJjzKtI0luBNTu5GjOcNMebnLTJbhlN6DAL0rPlBQHV9e5-sb8jKVRoCQQoQAvD_BwE) by @Steve Smith.

There is another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389169/best-practices-for-api-versioning?noredirect=1&lq=1).