# RESTful versioning... where to version in the URL?

Tags: web-services, http, rest

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [REST api versioning (only version the representation, not the resource itself)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024600/rest-api-versioning-only-version-the-representation-not-the-resource-itself)

Hello,

So I need to version my restful services.  I understand that many place `v1` or something similar in the URL to denote use of the "first version" of a resource.  My question is, where in the URL should the versioning portion go?

Most people do the following:

```
http://myDomain.com/v1/pictures/etc
```

However, I'm thinking that the following makes more sense:

```
http://myDomain.com/pictures/v1/etc
```

This denotes that you want to use version 1 of the "pictures" resource, however you could use a different version of other resources.  What are people's thoughts on this?

Thanks

Comment: you are right... these other questions have quite a bit of good info in them.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been covered here 
[REST api versioning (only version the representation, not the resource itself)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024600/rest-api-versioning-only-version-the-representation-not-the-resource-itself)

and here:

[How to version REST URIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972226/how-to-version-rest-uris)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter. If it's "restful", the client can discover the location by following links (be it in hypertext or in headers).