# REST Web API URL to update a resource property

Tags: asp.net-web-api

To update the resource i have exposed following reset web api url -

```
http://server.com/api/v1/{companyid}/resources/{resourceid}
```

and request body contains the resource to be updated.

I have also exposed a seperate API to update a property of same resource. From business rule perspective this is special property and cannot be updated/retrieved along with normal resource api.

So using following url to expose separate api as below -

```
http://server.com/api/v1/{companyid}/resources/{resourceid}/property?propertyKey=propertyValue
```

this does not sound good. Is there better approach?

Comment: I think that's fine. you could also do `api/v1/{companyid}/resources/{resourceid}/{property}`. Since it's an update, I assume the body of your `put` or `post` has the value to update that property to

Comment: In case of updating the resource body contains the resource model. In case of updating only the specific single property the value comes along with URL instead of body.

Comment: If you want to include that property value in the URL, then I think you're doing fine. You could alternatively do something like `PUT api/v1/{companyid}/resources/{resourceid}/{property}/{propertyvalue}`. Again, I think you're fine

Comment: Do NOT version URLs ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972226/how-to-version-rest-uris

Comment: @david-brabant, your right APIs are in beta release right now, with some debate over versioning approach internally. This will be the public facing apis in ecommerce domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer from the comments for others

`PUT api/v1/{companyid}/resources/{resourceid}/{property}` with the Body containing the value of the property is one way.

`PUT api/v1/{companyid}/resources/{resourceid}/{property}/{propertyvalue}` is another way if you want the value entirely in the URL.

Of course, `http://server.com/api/v1/{companyid}/resources/{resourceid}/property?propertyKey=propertyValue` is also probably fine.

As @David-Brabant mentioned [don't version your API's in the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972226/how-to-version-rest-uris)